# How to make image divide equally between two grids?

Tags: html, css, image

How to make image between two grid dives? That image would be 50% on one and 50% on another?

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sec-div">
  <img class="img-fluid img-second "src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 second">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do, which two elements are you trying to spread the img over?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/nen0akcb/) ?

Comment: http://www.templatemo.com/tm-243-web-design

Comment: i try to make like in this link that i send now. You see green and grey grid background. And in middle there are white element with information. So i would like in place of this element to put between  two grid backgrounds img . This is possible? How i could do it ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `z-index` to keep the `img` below - not sure if will be necessary, set the `body { background-color: gray }` and set the `margin` of the main `div` with a negative value. I think this will work.

Try this: (I'm assuming you're using Bootstrap)

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="header"></div>
<div class="container second">
  <div class="col-lg-12 ">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #header {
        padding: 2% 0% 5% 0%; /* you should control img height through here, as width will be viewport sized */
        background: url('images/pool.jpg');
        background-attachment: static;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: 0 /* try using this to set this div below the other */
    }

    .second {
       margin: /* negative value */
       z-index: /* bootstrap items have really high numbers, so I guess this won't be necessary */
    }
```

See it working here! https://jsfiddle.net/hokumi/m7qoy7h3/